# Speed up image loading in TImage

Tags: delphi-7, gdi+, delphi-10.2-tokyo, timage

How can I speed up image loading in `TImage` in Delphi 10.2?

I want to move a project from Delphi 7 to Delphi 10.2, but I'm having trouble loading files. In Delphi 10.2, images take much longer to load, and quality is lost.

In Delphi 7, it takes about 3 seconds. In Delphi 10.2, it takes 15 seconds.

From Delphi 7:

[image]

From Delphi 10.2:

[image]

This is how I load the file:

```
IMG.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + IMG.Hint);
```

I tried to connect GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ, GDIPUTIL, but it did not work.

I finally tried to make a program snippet to demonstrate my problem:
https://github.com/MrDimain/TestPicsSpeed.git

Comment: Have you checked compiler flags and directives?  The defaults may be different between the two compilers.

Comment: what parameters can affect the loading of images?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. What TYPE of image are you loading? PNG? GIF? JPG? BMP?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, surely if debug dcus are being used for the vcl, it will run slower.

Comment: i'm loading PNG and JPG images.

Comment: Is this in the IDE or runtime as well ?  maybe you should post a [a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only solution is to use WICImage.LoadFromFile
but loose some control like loading progress.